# Multiple tables in a single table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, join

I've downloaded the [Worlds-Country-State-and-City-Mysql-Database project](https://github.com/baraskar/Worlds-Country-State-and-City-Mysql-Database) from GitHub, it gives a database of countries, states, and cities.

Normally such databases are found in three tables for country, state, and city, but here it is only a single table, and it has all three pieces of data. It works fine but I can't understand how it works.

Here is snapshot of that table.
[image]

[image]

Somebody please explain this

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a parent-child relationship. The parent_ID column designates if a location belongs to another(is the child of another) Location_id.

For example to get the direct children (states) of Aruba, you would do a self join as such:

```
select * from mytable A
left join mytable B -- join same table
on b.parent_id=a.location_id -- with parent of the secondary being equal to the ID of the primary.
where a.location_id='Aruba'
```

If you want to get the children of the states(cities) , you would need one more self-join

Comment: But there is only one table here

Comment: that's exactly what I wrote in the query. You can use the same table multiple times, and even joining it to itself, as long as you use aliases (example above, they are A and B). It' called a self join

Comment: see the part about -- join same table

Comment: I need to know about the table structure not the query,how did he insert all the data in a single table?

Comment: that's a normal table. He could have inserted it in many ways. There's nothing special about it. Think of it as a location table with an extra column, parent_id, that explains which location belongs to another.